# how to identify and determine and fix the error shown in Tomcat logs

Tags: tomcat

I have an error as being returned as shown here
[deployed development](http://35.166.148.217/faces/index.xhtml)

I have viewed the TomCat Logs:

[image: TomCat Logs]

How can I identify the error?

Comment: From the looks it is a miss-configured server, however we'd need ot see the logs to be sure. Please upload any relevant sections of the log here using the code tag (if you can't figure out how to format the post I can edit it)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132162/discussion-on-question-by-jon-how-to-identify-and-determine-and-fix-the-error-sh). @StevenByrne, I've provided Jon with write access. They can now join the chat with you.

Answer (score 0):

The remote AWS logs are located under your Beanstalk, on the left side of the screen is a link LOGS, click it and download.